# Hard-coded Cell but dynamic Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have created a dynamic range in excel with collect data from a raw data table. This table is divided by country. Using Name Manager I created formula that pulls the country code from the cell B1 of my worksheet and automatically updates my tables.

The problem is that I need a different worksheet for each country. How can I keep the cell B1 hardcoded `$B$1` without locking the worksheet?

Here an example of a dynamic range that feed a series of one of my table.

```
=INDEX('raw data'!$A$401:$BO$443, MATCH("Rebels"&Belgium!$B$1, 'raw data'!$A$401:$A$443&'raw data'!$B$401:$B$443,0),3):INDEX('raw data'!$A$401:$BO$443, MATCH("Rebels"&Belgium!$B$1, 'raw data'!$A$401:$A$443&'raw data'!$B$401:$B$443,0),COUNTA('raw data'!$A$401:$BO$401))
```

If I recreate the same formula for each worksheet I would need more than 200 names.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... Don't you need 200 names? One for each worksheet? How are they used? Are they only used on the sheet in question? Can you explain a bit more....

Answer (score 0):

> How can I keep the cell B1 hardcoded $B$1 without locking the
>   worksheet?

I am not sure I totally understand your Q but if you want to lock an individual cell on a worksheet then this may help.

By default all cells in a worksheet are Locked.  However they only become really locked to the user when the worksheet is protected.

You could unlock all the cells in the worksheet and keep cell B1 locked and then protect the worksheet.  In this way cell B1 will be locked and all other cells on the worksheet will be accessible once the worksheet is protecetd.  If you want further assurance you can apply a password when protecting the worksheet.

If this is along the right lines for you then [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214081) may be helpful for you.

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this thread is it what you required from your Q?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your help.

It might be that I haven't explained myself properly. To make the graph automated and the data range dynamic I created a dynamic range using formulas like the example I put in my question.

As you may know to use such formulas to feed graphs you need to give the formula a name using name manager. As my workbook is composed by 21 worksheets that are exactly the same but related to 21 different countries I need to copy each worksheet and each worksheet will contain a different country code. As the situation is right now all the worksheet still look at the cell B1 of the first worksheet. So I need to know if there is any way to tell Excel "Yes I want you to look at cell B1 (Hardcoded) but in each worksheet. Because if I hardcode the cel $B$1 Excel hardcode also the worksheet (ex. Belgium) if I live the cell relative B1 it screws everything up.

Is it more clear now?